# What configuration setttings need to be made on a raspberry pi so as to add it to a new network?

Tags: networking

I have a home network consisting of a raspberry pi connected to a wifi router via an ethernet cable and a laptop (running windows) connected to the router wirelessly. My dilemma is if i get rid of my router and connect the raspberry pi directly to my laptop using the ethernet cable, will it function normally? Or will I have to make some changes in the network configuration of the pi before removing it from the router? I imagine that I may have to create a new network on windows but I also want to maintain the old network configuration on raspberry pi so that I can connect it back to the router easily.

Answer (score 1):

The Pi will be expecting to talk to a DHCP server when it starts up.  The DHCP server will give the Pi an IP address and act as a gateway to the wider network.

At the moment the router is acting as the DHCP server.

You have to configure your Windows box to act as a DHCP server (Google should show how).

Once you do that I think everything will work (not positive as I don't use Windows).

The Ethernet connection should automatically be used in preference to the wireless connection.

Comment: but the pi never got the ip address dynamically, I had assigned a static address to it by connecting the SD Card to my laptop and editing the cmdline.txt file and writing the static ip address...also, my raspberry pi doesnt have a wireless adapter so what wireless connection are you refering to?

Comment: @user3562053 My mistake, I misread your post and thought you were using the Pi wirelessly.  If you can't find out how to make the Windows box act as a DHCP server the next best thing would be to have the router always assign the same address as the PC.  That way it will be using the same address when connected to Windows and the router.  Check you router box and see if it can reserve a fixed IP address for a given physical (or MAC address).  The physical address is the hardware address of the Pi.  That way it shouldn't matter if you plug the Pi cable into the PC or the router.

Comment: I googled for it but i guess my router cannot store the ip address. Can't I do the reverse? I mean store the ip address that the router assigned (to the raspberry pi) in a windows box? is it possible? how do i do it?